# Lining up cells from two raster datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, rasterization

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 to convert a polygon feature class to a raster dataset and I would like the cells to line up with an existing raster layer.  I am running the feature to raster tool and using the existing raster layer as a reference for the cell size and as the snap raster.  However, my output raster cells are still offset as seen here:[image]

Any other suggestions for getting the cells to line up?  I have double checked that my existing raster and feature class are both in the same projection.

Update - I also tried the suggestions in the answer listed here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98483

I turned off background processing and used data from straight from the catalog and am receiving the same result.

Comment: What software are you using? or what software do you have available to use?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.  I have edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Well ... I was going to craft an answer based on using your original raster as a snap raster and also to set the cell size but it seems you are already doing that so I'm pretty flummoxed. I think I'd call ESRI support in a case like that. Are they also already in the same projection? - Ah - I see that now too. harumph!

Comment: Yes, both layers are currently in the same projection.  Yeah, I'm also a bit surprised as to why they are not lining up.

Comment: Can be just a visual thing with rasters, see if raster to polygon confirms mismatch

Answer (score 2):

Before running feature to raster, go into your 'Environment Settings' (access via 'Geoprocessing' tab) and set a 'Snap Raster' (under 'Processing Extent'). Under 'Raster Analysis' set your 'Cell Size' as the Snap Raster. Then run Feature to Raster. If that doesn't work, try processing the raster with another tool (e.g., raster calculator) after feature to raster. Also try in a new map document.

Comment: I tried all of these suggestions (several times and from a couple new map documents) with no success, unfortunately.

Comment: Do all of above and raster calculator on results

Comment: perhaps raster structure matters? it's working for me using .tif

Comment: As FelixIP mentioned, try running some other process on the raster (e.g. raster times 1).

Comment: Jus "raster" will do, no need to apply any transformation